# Tiles Integration with Struts 2 Annotation

Tags: struts2, annotations, tiles, tiles2

I have been trying to integrate Tiles with Struts 2 annotation based action but it's not working correctly.

As I don't have `struts-config.xml` and in every tutorial available at web they are referencing it with `struts-config.xml`.

First is it possible to integrate annotation based struts action with tiles. If yes then how?

```
@Action(value="/login",results={@Result(name="success",location="/home",type=TilesResult.class),
            @Result(name="login",location="/jsp/userLogin.jsp")})
    public String execute() {
```

This is what my code is but it always gives me error in MyEclipse at `TilesResult.class` that

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<TilesResult> to String
```

I have dependency in my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Can anyone help me how to add tiles in annotation based actions

---

I used `type="tiles"` instead of `type=TilesResult.class` then it has given me below exception

```
Caused by: The Result type [tiles] which is defined in the Result annotation on the class [class com.actions.LoginAction] or determined by the file extension or is the default result type for the PackageConfig of the action, could not be found as a result-type defined for the Struts/XWork package [com.actions#convention-default#] - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultResultMapBuilder.createResultConfig(DefaultResultMapBuilder.java:422)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultResultMapBuilder.createFromAnnotations(DefaultResultMapBuilder.java:394)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultResultMapBuilder.build(DefaultResultMapBuilder.java:202)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.createActionConfig(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:800)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildConfiguration(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:586)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:318)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.ClasspathPackageProvider.loadPackages(ClasspathPackageProvider.java:53)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:204)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
```

Comment: Did you try with `type="tiles"`? Also you'll need to make sure your parent package extend the tiles default.

Comment: Yes I did but after that it has given me following exception: Post Updated

Comment: Make sure you have codebehind plugin included with the deployment.

Comment: @RomanC what exactly do you mean by codebehind plugin??

Comment: @WasifKirmani http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/codebehind-plugin.html

Comment: @RomanC I am not using this plugin it's deprecated too... so I am just trying to integrate tiles with my struts 2 but without xml gluecode i.e. struts.xml and stuff..

Comment: @WasifKirmani Really, what is the code from your question, clarify and update it. Because your annotation looks like codebehind based.

Comment: @RomanC it was simply struts2 with tiles integration but using annotation not struts.xml. So, in this case I am not completely sure about the result-type annotation. Because in struts.xml we must need to define something like
 <result-types>
08.
<result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
09.
</result-types>
but, here in my case i don't want struts.xml so how to achieve it this is my main questio

Comment: @WasifKirmani Incorrect usage of annotations, I didn't see that is a one of the major problem in your question and not codebehind related, anyway your version is outdated.

Comment: @RomanC which version is out dated can you elaborate??

Comment: @WasifKirmani The version of tiles plugin.

Comment: @RomanC which version do i need to use then?? as my struts library is 2.1.8

Comment: @WasifKirmani Exactly, this version of struts library and plugin.

Comment: So in my case both are same... 2.1.8
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
 <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.1.8</version>
</dependency>
            
           <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
     <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.8</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: @WasifKirmani I have no more questions to you.

Comment: Your action needs to be in a package that extends the tiles package, as I said.

Comment: @DaveNewton But this is the confusion I don't have any struts.xml file as using annotations. So, how can I extend my package with tiles package using annotation??

Comment: By reading the docs and using the appropriate parent package.

Answer (score 4):

Try these :

1. Use `type="tiles"` instead of `type="TilesResult.class"`
2. Use your target tile definition, `location="tiles-definition-name"`, instead of JSP page, `location="/jsp/userLogin.jsp"`, in your result location
3. Have following in your `web.xml`:

   `<context-param>
   <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <listener>
   <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
   </listener>`
4. Have following in your `struts.xml` (If you are using annotations alone and no `struts.xml`, then you have to create a minimal one for this because there's no annotation available to define a custom result type)

   `<struts>
   <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="codeoftheday.blogspot.com"/>
   <package name="codeoftheday.blogspot.com" extends="struts-default">
   <result-types>
   <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
   </result-types> 
   </package>
   </struts>`

**NOTE:** I've written a detailed blog post here on this issue - [Maven, Struts2 Annotations and Tiles Integration Example via Convention / Codebehind / Zero Config plugin using Eclipse IDE](http://codeoftheday.blogspot.com/2013/07/maven-struts2-annotations-and-tiles.html)

Comment: Basically I am using annotation with tiles and it's giving me another exception i have done that too
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]

Comment: @Syed Muhammad Humayun Is Struts 2.5.10.1 support annotation for result-type tag or any other alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

1. "org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG" this definition is not available with Strut 2.5.10.1
2. I have used following jars in my project.

   - struts2-core-2.5.10.1
   - struts2-convention-plugin-2.5.10.1
   - struts2-tiles-plugin-2.5.10.1
   - javax.servlet-api-3.0.1

Please once you compare your web.xml with following code.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.demo.action</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<context-param>
    <!-- <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name> -->
    <param-name>org.apache.tiles.definition.DefinitionsFactory.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/tiles.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```