# Annotation based configuration alternative for tag result-type of struts.xml

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, annotations, tiles

I'm trying to create new Struts 2 application (annotation based configuration) with common header, footer and body where body change on menu click.

So I referred to this link which says [If you are using annotations alone and no `struts.xml`, then you have to create a minimal one for this because there's no annotation available to define a custom result type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17773760/4281343).

Do i still have to create `struts.xml` for `result-type` tag?

I am trying to use Tiles 3 and getting this error:

```
Jun 17, 2017 3:26:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:499)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:75)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4590)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5233)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:906)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:486)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: The Result type [tiles] which is defined in the Result annotation on the class [class org.iibf.crf.action.LoginAction] or determined by the file extension or is the default result type for the PackageConfig of the action, could not be found as a result-type defined for the Struts/XWork package [org.iibf.crf.action#convention-default#/] - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultResultMapBuilder.createResultConfig(DefaultResultMapBuilder.java:443)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultResultMapBuilder.createFromAnnotations(DefaultResultMapBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultResultMapBuilder.createResultsFromAnnotations(DefaultResultMapBuilder.java:222)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.DefaultResultMapBuilder.build(DefaultResultMapBuilder.java:192)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.createActionConfig(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:948)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildConfiguration(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:700)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.buildActionConfigs(PackageBasedActionConfigBuilder.java:336)
    at org.apache.struts2.convention.ClasspathPackageProvider.loadPackages(ClasspathPackageProvider.java:53)
    at com.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default parent package should be *not* `convention-default` but `tiles-default`. You can distinguish this if you add a tiles plugin to the classpath and set the `@ParentPackage("tiles-default")` annotation to the action class. You can put this annotation on the class or package where it's applied by the retention policy.

Also note, that you can define the parent package globally, not only the custom action class from the previous example. I.e., if you have a package `default` in your configuration that extends `tiles-default` and you want to configure it globally use

```
<constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="default"/>
```

Comment: Do i still have to include struts.xml file with this code ? is there any other struts-convention based alternative(any link with some code will be help full)

Comment: With this code you should use `struts.xml`, however there are alternatives to provide configuration settings via properties file or init parameters of the filter configuration in `web.xml` or `@WebFilter` annotation. If you are looking for convention based solution then you should place annotation on the base class or package. The configuration that is created by convention is configured for `convention-default` parent package.